# How to get an array of fixed size squares from a bigger square?

Tags: php, math

I’m trying to get the array of fixed size squares from a bigger square. For example:

I have coordinates of a square:

```
$x1 = 1;
$x2 = 100;
$y1 = 1;
$y2 = 100;
$smallerSquareSide = 10;
```

What I expect as result:

```
$res = [[1,10,1,10],[11,20,1,10],[21,30,1,10],…]
```

But I have no idea how to do that correctly.

P.S. there may be empty spaces around the borders because the numbers might not match

Comment: It looks like it should just be nested loops, one for X and another for Y.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this should work (format of output: res=[square1, square2, square3, ...], squareN=[x1, x2, y1, y2])

```
$x1 = 1;
$x2 = 100;
$y1 = 1;
$y2 = 100;
$smallerSquareSide = 10;

$res = [];
for($i=$y1; $i+($smallerSquareSide-1)<=$y2; $i+=$smallerSquareSide){  // loop y
    for($j=$x1; $j+($smallerSquareSide-1)<=$x2; $j+=$smallerSquareSide){  // loop x
        // add next square coords -> [$j, $j+($smallerSquareSide-1), $i, $i+($smallerSquareSide-1)]
        array_push($res, [$j, $j+($smallerSquareSide-1), $i, $i+($smallerSquareSide-1)]);
    }
}
```